# I want to work on the HTML on a site with a JS wysiwyg/wysiwym box that doesn't let me see/edit the html output.

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg

Is there a way to block the editor from loading in the browser so I can work on the actual HTML?

The editor in question is wymeditor. I can't turn off javascript completely because the rest of the page won't load.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### When the window loaded...

add the editor's script in page head, which will create the editor's element on body.

It'd be like this:

```
window.onload=function(){
    document.head.appendChild('<script type="text/javascript" src="editor.js"></script>');
}
```